# dynamic select query for spring jdbc inbound adapter

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc

Can i define a dynamic query to jdbc inbound channel adapter?

```
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter max-rows-per-poll="1" 
    query ="#{'select * from work where status=0 and and test='' + test.testValue+ '' order by date_modified'}"     
    channel="test" data-source="testDS" update="update work set status=1 where id in (:id)"
   >       
    <int:poller fixed-rate="100">
        <int:transactional transaction-manager="testTM"/>           
    </int:poller>       
</int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Here I have a test bean defined and it has a method getTestValue().
This is not working.
any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use select-sql-parameter-source attribute of int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter

```
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter query="select * from user where lower(username)=:key"
channel="inputChannel" data-source="dataSource"
update="UPDATE DUMMY SET DUMMY_VALUE='test'" row-mapper="personResultMapper"
select-sql-parameter-source="parameterSource" />

<bean id="parameterSource" class="Class to extend AbstractSqlParameterSource" />
```

The class that extends AbstractSqlParameterSource is responsible for supplying value for parameter.

More details can be found at: https://gist.github.com/dsyer/472357